# Ionic5 Capacitor and React Style Android Status Bar

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

Im trying to get this to work, but because its my first time developing a ionic/react app i have no clue how to get this working... If i build a apk of my app and run it on my device the defalt android status bar is black which does not match with my white app. I found this documentation here which should fit:

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/status-bar

So i did this like in the documentation described:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { StatusBar } = Plugins;
StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({
  color: 'white',
});
```

Now the Statusbar is white, but i want to have the default icons like wlan, push notifications to be black which are now white too and fade into the white background. How can i do this?

I tried the following code but after that my app wont boot up anymore. Could anybody please help me here?

```
StatusBarStyle.setStyle({
  style: "DARK",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.setStyle](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/status-bar#setstyle) function with two Types: [Dark and Light](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/status-bar#statusbarstyle)

Comment: That wont work. It has zero impact on the status bar.